# How to count only shown in filter heading using COUNTIF (Excel 2010)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, countif

I have a list of names, company, meals etc. and there is a filter in each column.

In the top, there is a list of the 5 type of meals, and `COUNTIF()` is used to count the different types of meal in the list. When filtered on the heading in the column, the total list of five types in the top still count all as if there is no filter.

How can this be solved so that it only counts the meals shown if filtered in one of the columns?

I am using Excel 2010.

[image]

Comment: I take it you're using Microsoft Excel? Always helps to state which software (and version) you're using.

Comment: Also it may help to post a link to an image showing what you're looking at so it's easier for us to visualise what your problem is - if you take a screenshot you can upload it to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com)

Comment: Yes it`s Excel 2010. I tried to upload a picture in the question, but I was not allowed to that. imgur.com seems to be a nice service, so I have added a screenshot there. http://imgur.com/8XbfHls

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Have a read of this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323194/how-do-i-only-count-visible-rows-when-using-the-countifs-function or this article from Chandoo: http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/06/07/formula-forensics-023/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work -

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(H9,ROW(H:H)-ROW(H9),0)),(H:H="Breakfast")+0)
```

Adjust according to where your data is.